# Redial or reload a href tel if the number is engaged

Tags: android, href, tel

I am using an href tel: to successfully create a clickable link for mobile phones such as Android. However, if the number is engaged/busy (unreachable) there seems to be no fall=back option to redial or reload the page.

Is it possible to refresh or redial the page if this happens from within the OS?

Answer (score 0):

That functionality would clearly lie outside the control of a website or web app, since it will have transferred control of the call over to the phone application by that point.

So no, you're not going to be able to get a "callback" or the like from the phone application to the webpage indicating failure.  Indeed, that might be a privacy concern anyway.

As far as refreshing or redialing, the closest you might get is to put a "refresh page" hook on the action of clicking a href tel: link with javascript, which is a relatively trivial procedure that is well documented elsewhere.